# issue installing bazel on raspberry pi 4 (ubuntu 19.10)

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, bazel

I trying to install Bazel on raspberry pi 4 (ubuntu 19.10).
I follow the guide for installing Bazel from [install Bazel for ubuntu](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-ubuntu.html).
It's failed with the error (see full output below).
when running the script I get this error but the result is Success

> home/ubuntu/bin/bazel: line 89: /home/ubuntu/.bazel/bin/bazel-real:
>   cannot execute binary file: Exec format error /home/ubuntu/bin/bazel:
>   line 89: /home/ubuntu/.bazel/bin/bazel-real: Success

the install bazel command returns this error:

> E: Unable to locate package bazel

I gest because it fail to install the script.

I try other versions with the same result, what am I doing wrong?
Is there support f for raspberry pi 4  / ubuntu 19.10?

> ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ ./bazel-1.1.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh --user
>
> ### Bazel installer
>
> Bazel is bundled with software licensed under the GPLv2 with Classpath
>   exception.  You can find the sources next to the installer on our
>   release page:  https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases
>
> ## Release 1.1.0 (2019-10-21)
>
> Baseline: d9fe1d4078c25912427c9b2e79e115f4ee9b7ab8
>
> Cherry picks:
>
> - 0a8071af47223989e9ba335e63b8a9595fe6f10f:  Upgrade java_tools to javac11-v6.1
>
> Important changes:
>
> - The query flag "--host_deps" (commonly used as "--nohost_deps")  has been renamed to "--tool_deps", and now also removes  dependencies in
>     any execution configuration from being reported  in the query output.
>     The previous flag name is deprecated and  will be removed in a future
>     release.
> - The `cc_common.{compile,link}` APIs can now be used without  passing the `--experimental_cc_skylark_api_enabled_packages` flag.
> - A list of log paths will be provided in build output.
> - Improve runfiles documentation.
> - Improve documentation on rule outputs.
> - BUILD/.bzl execution errors cause execution to stop, even at  top-level
> - Multiple Starlark validation errors are reported in a single pass.
> - Introduce --experimental_nested_set_as_skykey_threshold
>
> This release contains contributions from many people at Google, as
>   well as Andrew Suffield, Austin Schuh, Bor Kae Hwang, Brian
>   Richardson, Christy Norman, Clint Harrison, Dan Halperin, Dave Lee,
>   David Neil, David Ostrovsky, George Gensure, Greg Estren, Greg, Jacob
>   Parker, Jakub Bujny, John Millikin, Keith Smiley, Laurent Le Brun,
>   marcohu, Marwan Tammam, Mostyn Bramley-Moore, Stepan Koltsov, Thi Don,
>   Thi, Tomasz Strejczek.
>
> ### Build information
>
> - [Commit](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/8075057)  Uncompressing....../home/ubuntu/bin/bazel: line 89:
>     /home/ubuntu/.bazel/bin/bazel-real: cannot execute binary file: Exec
>     format error  /home/ubuntu/bin/bazel: line 89:
>     /home/ubuntu/.bazel/bin/bazel-real: Success
>
> ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bazel
>   Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan InRelease 
>   Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-updates InRelease 
>   Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-backports InRelease 
>   Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-security InRelease 
>   Hit:5 https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable InRelease 
>   Reading package lists... Done  Reading package lists... Done  Building
>   dependency tree  Reading state information... Done  E: Unable to
>   locate package bazel

Answer (score 1):

Bazel release binaries are built for x86_64.

You'll need to [bootstrap Bazel](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-compile-source.html#bootstrap-bazel) on the device.

Comment: I try this and it's failed in the build

Comment: ERROR: /home/ubuntu/bazel/third_party/grpc/BUILD:386:1: C++ compilation of rule '//third_party/grpc:gpr_base' failed (Exit 1)
third_party/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/log_linux.cc:43:13: error: ambiguating new declaration of 'long int gettid()'
   43 | static long gettid(void) { return syscall(__NR_gettid); }
      |             ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:1170,
             from third_party/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/log_linux.cc:41:
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/unistd_ext.h:34:16: note: old declaration '__pid_t gettid()'
34 | extern __pid_t gettid (void) __THROW;

Comment: |                ^~~~~~
third_party/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/log_linux.cc:43:13: warning: 'long int gettid()' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
   43 | static long gettid(void) { return syscall(__NR_gettid); }
      |             ^~~~~~
Target //src:bazel_nojdk failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 485.509s, Critical Path: 43.25s
INFO: 306 processes: 306 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully

ERROR: Could not build Bazel